# How can I change the system shell used by perl for system(), qx//, and friends?

Tags: windows, perl

I'd like to replace the shell perl uses for `system`; for example to replace `cmd.exe` on Windows with bash. Is there a supported mechanism to tell perl what  shell to use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perl ignores the value of `COMSPEC`, but you can set the environment variable `PERL5SHELL` to the path to a shell program file, together with any switches that you want to use. For instance

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /d /c
```

Perl will use this to run command strings that you pass to `qx//` and `system($command)` where `$command` contains shell metacharacters

But there is no bash shell on Windows by default, and you will have to install something like [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com) or [win-bash](http://win-bash.sourceforge.net) before you can use a bash-type shell

Comment: *puts on Burns' voice* ...  egggggcellent

Comment: @BillyONeal: At a guess *Burns* is someone known to US residents? To me he's the Scottish poet, who would have pronounced his gees rather differently

Comment: @BillyONeal: Ah *that* Mr Burns :)  We do know about Springfield here but he's not the first "Burns" that most people would think of! Glad to have helped. Cheers