# Controlling what Perl considers the 'system shell'

Tags: windows, perl

I am running an externally supplied perl script (the OpenSSL configure script if you are interested).  It contains the line:

```
my $vew=`nasmw -v 2>NUL`;
```

I am running on Windows, but I am using the version of perl which ships with  git version 2.19.0.windows.1, and this appears to by a Cygwin perl which uses sh to execute backticks.  The problem is that this creates a file called 'NUL' rather than throwing stderr away.  Amongst other things you can't delete such a file from Explorer or the command line.  (You can via bash).

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35668359/771073) but setting PERL5SHELL to `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C` doesn't stop the file being created.

Is there a way of controlling the shell that a Cygwin perl uses?

Perl -v reports version 5.26.2

(The obvious workround is to patch `NUL` to `/dev/null` but I'd rather not do that if I can avoid it.)

Comment: The easiest workaround might be to use a regular Windows Perl like Strawberry Perl. Mixing Cygwin and Windows libs can be complicated.

Comment: @Grinnz Tell me about it - but that involves changing all the build machines...

Comment: Cheap and cheerful workround:  I'm running this all from a bash script anyway.  Just `rm -f NUL` after running the perl script.